# Dynamic php pages

Tags: php, ajax, dynamic, view

I have a header and a main div on my site. How can I create dynamic pages without refreshing the page, by just placing the files from profile.php, search.php and so on inside the main div of my website through using navigation menu?

For example, I have profile.php as the users main interface, and using `?action=action` I have achieved the dynamic pages. But when it comes to search, I have to redirect the user to `search.php?query=search-text` and so on for the other pages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want to do [content replacement using AJAX](http://events.manzwebdesigns.com/?p=111).

Comment: is ajax the only solution here?cant it be done via php only?

thanks, will checkout the link

Comment: If you don't want to page refresh to happen, then yes, you'll have to use AJAX.

Comment: What about a curl script in PHP?

Comment: I'm not sure what a curl script would achieve - would it not require a page refresh? And if so, then why not just use a PHP include?

Comment: The only options you have if you don't want page refresh, is to use AJAX or Frames. Frames are bad practice, so use AJAX.

Comment: I haven't used one personally, I had a guy I was working with use one because we had to get a response from an external XML web-service and AJAX doesn't allow that. Worked a treat.

Comment: That'd be due to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: Indeed. So seems like an overcomplicated method - but strictly PHP if it really needs to be that way.

Comment: so it seems the best solution for now is to use jquery or i can create a new file caled search.php and load this new file for the search results...

Comment: Correct. Although remember, it's the web - people are used to reloading pages!

Answer (score 2):

Using JQuery you can do

```
$('#divid').load( "URL" )
```

Using Javascript and Frames are the only ways to do this without refreshing the header. Frames are considered bad pracice, so AJAX and JQuery are your best option here.

Comment: I did it your way once, and someone showed me the load function. Makes life a lot easier! JQuery is great for adding useful tools that save a few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.

If you are not using a framework (it looks like you are not) you can just use include/require to bring whole chunks of code into your file (requires a page refresh).

If you are using a framework that supports the MVC structure, then you will just include multiple views to build your response page.  The syntax differs between different frameworks, so sorry no example code for you (requires a page refresh).

Also you could use AJAX.  Note, AJAX is not a new programming language. It is using Javascript to execute an independent call on the end-user's browser to your server at a special page/handler.  The server side handler script then processes your request and returns a snippet of HTML code or a small block of text which is then received by your end-users browser and then dynamically inserted into the DOM (no page refresh).

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know how to achieve this would be requesting content with AJAX and setting the content of your div to being the result - might not be the most ideal (not sure as I've never looked into it) but that's how I would go about it. JQuery would make this easy like so:

```
function loadPage(pg)
{
    var container = $("#container");

    $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        data: "page="+pg,
        url: "loadhtml.php",

        success: function(result)
        {
            container.html(result);
        }
    });
}
```